# Meteor Sending dynamic urls through email

Tags: email, meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to send a dynamic url using a template. I want to direct users to a specific link, but I'm not sure how to do that dynamically? I can just hardcode the url, but would prefer to use dynamic urls in case I make changes in the future.

here's what I have, I realize that trying to store a url variable like this

> url: "{{pathFor 'welcome'}}"

is pretty dumb, but I can't figure out how to do this. Any help is appreciated! This is what I have:

```
var dataContext = {
      message: "To set up your profile follow the link",
      url: "{{pathFor 'welcome'}}",
      hyperlinkText: "Get Started",
      title: "Welcome to site!"
    };


    var html = Blaze.toHTMLWithData(Template.emailTemplate, dataContext);
    var from = "myemail@mysite.com";
    var to = currentUser.emails[0].address;
    var subject = "Welcome to site";

    Meteor.call("sendEmail", to, from, subject, html);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript just evaluate `Router.path(pathName)` to get the path. You can get the base path with `Meteor.absoluteUrl()`. Note that the former will include a leading / while the latter includes a trailing / so you'll need to remove one. Ex:

```
function dynamicPath(pathName){
  return Meteor.absoluteUrl() + Router.path(pathName).substr(1);
}
```

Comment: To simply get route url, you can just call `Router.url(...)` instead of `Router.path(...)`.
There is also a helper to do this in template : `{{urlFor ...}}` instead of `{{pathFor ...}}`.

Note that your code isn't very secure... from client, anyone is able to send emails from your platform to anyone with anything !